# Kafka LDAP and RBAC

Tags: apache-kafka, ldap, confluent-platform, rbac

I want to set up authorization and Role models using LDAP and RBAC for Kafka.

For example i have following role bindings:

> role1: read/write for topic1, topic2 if the user is a member of a
> LDAP group1
>
> role2: read/write for topic3, topic4 if the user is a member of a
> LDAP group2

LDAP:

> user1 (group1), user2 (group1), user3(group1)
>
> user4 (group2), user5 (group2), user6(group2)

I create bindings:

```
confluent iam rolebinding create --principal Group:group1 --role role1 --resource Topic:topic1 --kafka-cluster-id $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID

confluent iam rolebinding create --principal Group:group1 --role role1 --resource Topic:topic2 --kafka-cluster-id $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID

confluent iam rolebinding create --principal Group:group2 --role role2 --resource Topic:topic3 --kafka-cluster-id $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID

confluent iam rolebinding create --principal Group:group2 --role role2 --resource Topic:topic4--kafka-cluster-id $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID
```

it doesn't work. Is there a correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, confluent does not support custom roles.  A predefined list can be found at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/rbac/rbac-predefined-roles.html#role-based-access-control-predefined-roles

For brevity, the list is here:

SysAdmin
UserAdmin
SecurityAdmin
ClusterAdmin
DeveloperManage
DeveloperWrite
DeveloperRead
ResourceOwner
AuditAdmin
Operator

Comment: What is confluent's relationship to Kafka?

Comment: I see that this topic is 2 years old. Does anyone know if custom roles are now available in Confluent Cloud ? Thanks,